# Chrome extensions Invalid value

Tags: google-chrome-extension

getting  error Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid scheme.

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "MyExtension",
"version": "1.0",    
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "js": ["background.js"],
        "matches": ["ftm://*"]
    }
  ],

 "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
```

}

my background.js

```
 chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {

var url = launchData.url;
alert(url);
```

});

Comment: As the error says `ftm://` is an invalid scheme. See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Comment: if change      "matches": ["http://ftm/*"] it is okey

Comment: It won't work anyway. Chrome can't display pages that have ftm:// URLs so it can't run a content script there.

Comment: look down below please

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do because 1) Chrome can't display ftm:// URLs, 2) extensions can't use chrome.app.runtime.

Comment: how do you advise to get around chrome.app.runtime?

Comment: chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
    var url = launchData.url;
    alert(url);
});